wpa_supplicant "CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed" with "wired" driver
I tried to run wpa_supplicant with a wired connection. But then it failed with a message "EAP authentication failed". The IP address was taken off the connection. Can you tell me what is wrong?
my wpa_supplicant-1.conf:
ap_scan=0
network={
key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
identity="test"
password="test"
eapol_flags=0
eap=MD5
}

I run wpa_supplicant with the command:
wpa_supplicant -s -dd -D wired -i eth3 -c /tmp/wpa_supplicant-1.conf
Here is the complete output with debugging information from the wpa_supplicant.:
#00579 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: wpa_supplicant v2.9
#00580 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
#00581 Aug 23 18:44:24 [NOTE] wpa_supplicant[1524]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
#00582 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: Initializing interface 'eth3' conf '/tmp/wpa_supplicant-1.conf' driver 'wired' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
#00583 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: Configuration file '/tmp/wpa_supplicant-1.conf' -> '/tmp/wpa_supplicant-1.conf'
#00584 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: Reading configuration file '/tmp/wpa_supplicant-1.conf'
#00585 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: ap_scan=0
#00586 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: Line: 2 - start of a new network block
#00587 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: key_mgmt: 0x8
#00588 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: identity - hexdump(len=4): 74 65 73 74
#00589 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: password - hexdump(len=4): [REMOVED]
#00590 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eapol_flags=0 (0x0)
#00591 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eap methods - hexdump(len=16): 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
#00592 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: Priority group 0
#00593 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]:    id=0 ssid=''
#00594 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: driver_wired_init_common: Added multicast membership with packet socket
#00595 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: Add interface eth3 to a new radio N/A
#00596 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Own MAC address: 00:0c:43:26:60:86
#00597 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
#00598 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Setting scan request: 0.100000 sec
#00599 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: WPS: UUID based on MAC address: d0707dc8-1440-54c0-bcb7-4fc64b26fdaf
#00600 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
#00601 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
#00602 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
#00603 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
#00604 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
#00605 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Added interface eth3
#00606 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: State: DISCONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
#00607 Aug 23 18:44:24 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: random: Got 17/20 bytes from /dev/random
#00608 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
#00609 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: External notification - EAP fail=0
#00610 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: External notification - portControl=Auto
#00611 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Already associated with a configured network - generating associated event
#00612 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Event ASSOC (0) received
#00613 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Association info event
#00614 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: State: DISCONNECTED -> ASSOCIATED
#00615 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Associated to a new BSS: BSSID=01:80:c2:00:00:03
#00616 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Select network based on association information
#00617 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Network configuration found for the current AP
#00618 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: WPA: clearing AP WPA IE
#00619 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: WPA: clearing AP RSN IE
#00620 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: WPA: clearing own WPA/RSN IE
#00621 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Failed to get scan results
#00622 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
#00623 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: External notification - EAP fail=0
#00624 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: External notification - portControl=Auto
#00625 Aug 23 18:44:25 [NOTE] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Associated with 01:80:c2:00:00:03
#00626 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: WPA: Association event - clear replay counter
#00627 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: WPA: Clear old PTK
#00628 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
#00629 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
#00630 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=1
#00631 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state CONNECTING
#00632 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state IDLE
#00633 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAP: EAP entering state INITIALIZE
#00634 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAP: EAP entering state IDLE
#00635 Aug 23 18:44:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: Cancelling scan request
#00636 Aug 23 18:44:25 [NOTE] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
#00637 Aug 23 18:44:26 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: startWhen --> 0
#00638 Aug 23 18:44:26 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state CONNECTING
#00639 Aug 23 18:44:26 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: txStart
#00640 Aug 23 18:44:26 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: TX EAPOL: dst=01:80:c2:00:00:03
#00641 Aug 23 18:44:26 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: TX EAPOL - hexdump(len=4): 01 01 00 00
#00642 Aug 23 18:44:29 [INFO] igmpx[1323]: added membership for 239.255.255.100 on upstream #0 192.168.155.82
#00643 Aug 23 18:44:29 [NOTE] igmpx[1323]: added new route 239.255.255.100: 192.168.155.82 -> 192.168.0.1
#00644 Aug 23 18:44:29 [NOTE] igmpx[1323]: enabling load filter
#00645 Aug 23 18:44:29 [INFO] update_IGMPX[1526]: [JOIN] Ifname: eth3  Group: 239.255.255.100
#00646 Aug 23 18:44:36 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: random: Got 3/3 bytes from /dev/random
#00647 Aug 23 18:44:57 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: startWhen --> 0
#00648 Aug 23 18:44:57 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state CONNECTING
#00649 Aug 23 18:44:57 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: txStart
#00650 Aug 23 18:44:57 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: TX EAPOL: dst=01:80:c2:00:00:03
#00651 Aug 23 18:44:57 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: TX EAPOL - hexdump(len=4): 01 01 00 00
#00652 Aug 23 18:45:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: idleWhile --> 0
#00655 Aug 23 18:45:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAP: EAP entering state FAILURE
#00656 Aug 23 18:45:25 [NOTE] wpa_supplicant[1524]: eth3: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
#00657 Aug 23 18:45:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state AUTHENTICATING
#00658 Aug 23 18:45:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state FAIL
#00659 Aug 23 18:45:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state HELD
#00660 Aug 23 18:45:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
#00661 Aug 23 18:45:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state IDLE
#00662 Aug 23 18:45:25 [ DBG] wpa_supplicant[1524]: EAPOL authentication completed - result=FAILURE

what is the problem?
